# Trying to create a graph from a txt file using python but getting a diagonal line

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, text

Im creating a little program using python, mathplotlib and numpy but im' getting this strange red line. This is the code and a piece of the txt file (It's 4000lines).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

file_name = 0
data = np.genfromtxt('File.txt', unpack=True, usecols=range(5))
x = data[0]

y1 = data[1] # the first graph
y2 = data[2] # the second graph
y3 = data[3] # the third graph
y4 = data[4] # the fourth graph

plt.plot(x, y1)
plt.plot(x, y2)
plt.plot(x, y3)
plt.plot(x, y4)
plt.plot()
plt.xlabel('Action')
plt.ylabel('Rate')
plt.title('Plot of Rate')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

The txt:

```
0   84  1   25  11
1   84  1   28  11
2   84  1   30  10
3   85  2   33  10
4   85  2   34  10
5   86  3   35  10
6   86  3   35  10
7   86  3   35  10
8   85  4   35  11
9   85  4   34  11
10  85  5   32  11
```

I tried changing the x and y values but nothing.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. A purely diagonal plot typically means the data is in string format rather than numeric. Verify the `dtype` of your arrays.

Comment: and remember to explicitly include `dtype=...` in your call to `genfromtxt`. It's "nice" that numpy will try to autodetect what types to use, but it's even nicer to write code that doesn't rely on magic =)

Comment: Thank you soo much, now it works. I was working on it all afternoon. You saved my evening.

Answer (score 0):

When you get a diagonal plot in Matplotlib that usually means the data are strings rather than numerical values, see the [Matplotlib FAQ page](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/faq.html#why-do-i-have-so-many-ticks-and-or-why-are-they-out-of-order).

The `np.genfromtxt` is seemingly reading the data in as a string. I can't explain why without the actual text file, but you can explicitly tell numpy what data type to use by setting the `dtype` argument when calling `np.genfromtxt`. In your example you have integers so you can use `dtype=int`.